# How to make the 'not exist' faster

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I have a problem. My DB is Oracle 9. Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct A.person_id)
        INTO p_record_count
        FROM A,
             B,
             F,
             T
       WHERE B.position_id = F.position_id **--Normal bussiness association**
         AND T.field2 = A.org_id           **--Normal bussiness association**
         AND F.Organization_Id = A.org_id  **--Normal bussiness association**
         AND A.person_id = F.person_id     **--Normal bussiness association**
         AND F.primary_flag = 'Y'          **--Normal bussiness association**
         and sysdate between F.effective_start_date and
             F.effective_end_date          **--Normal bussiness association**
         AND NOT EXISTS                    --very slow
                (SELECT log.person_id
                FROM cper.ehr_access_log log
               WHERE log.person_id = A.person_id
                 AND log.access_page = 'login.do'
                 AND trunc(log.access_time) BETWEEN
                     to_date(p_startDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND
                     to_date(p_endDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
         AND A.enable_flag = 'Y';            **--Normal bussiness association**
```

Requirement: Get people who didn't login.

The logic: Get all people I can get, then minus the people who login.

I have only a table with the login records.

Table cper.ehr_access_log has more than 10M records. It is a log table. This SQL takes about 30seconds.

### Within 5s is possible? Thanks for your help.

Thank you~!I will try.Have a good weekend~ : )

Comment: What does this A, B, F, T contains?

Comment: @Siva A:person INFO;F:person ASSIGNMENTS;P person position,T a small bussiness table.A contains 30K records.F contains 1M records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Table cper.ehr_access_log has more than 10M records.It is a log
>   table.This sql takes about 30seconds. Within 5s is possible?

I would say it is not possible without adding some indexes. But you might want to try the following suggestions

- Use a query plan to identify the hotspot. That will likely be tablescan required for `ehr_access_log` and you can probably use that argument to convince others that you need the index.
- Try replacing subquery with outer join as others have suggested
- You have joins on `B` and `T` but not predicates on them. Do you really need them in the query?
- You might be able to save some time by avoiding `trunc` calls (not sure). As an alternative, modify `p_startDate` beginning of day and `p_endDate` to end of day

Comment: +1 Amending the date selection to avoid the trunc should make it sargable, and able to make use of any indexes on the date column. Due to difficulties in determining an end of date value (0.1s to midnight?) this condition might best be expressed as something like `log.access_time >= to_date(p_startDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND log.access_time < to_date(p_endDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')+1` .

Answer (score 2):

The 'not exists' part of your query is known as a correlated subquery.  You can generally get better performance if you re-write as an OUTER join.

The pattern is

```
select a from b where not exists (select 1 from c where b.a = c.a)
```

becomes

```
select a from b left outer join c on b.a = c.a where c.a is null
```

Answer (score 1):

For a better performance, you must **INDEX** the table **`cper.ehr_access_log`**

Since it is a LOG table, make a monthly schedule to INDEX this table based on **`person_id`**. This will reduce some amount of time in quering.

Comment: Records of this table changing every second.I wanna INDEX on person_id,but I have no purview. lol..

Answer (score 1):

I think you can optimize you query by selecting only DISTINCT log.person_id records, it will decrease amount of records from your log.

You can also try to make an EXCLUDE from the first part:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct A.person_id)
    INTO p_record_count
    FROM A,
         B,
         F,
         T
   LEFT OUTER JOIN cper.ehr_access_log log
     ON log.person_id = A.person_id
        AND log.access_page = 'login.do'
        AND trunc(log.access_time) BETWEEN
        to_date(p_startDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND
        to_date(p_endDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
   WHERE B.position_id = F.position_id **--Normal bussiness association**
     AND T.field2 = A.org_id           **--Normal bussiness association**
     AND F.Organization_Id = A.org_id  **--Normal bussiness association**
     AND A.person_id = F.person_id     **--Normal bussiness association**
     AND F.primary_flag = 'Y'          **--Normal bussiness association**
     and sysdate between F.effective_start_date and
         F.effective_end_date          **--Normal bussiness association**
     AND log.person_id IS null
     AND A.enable_flag = 'Y';            **--Normal bussiness association**
```

Comment: This is a fail-should-die mission,I will try all possible situtations and then deside which way to go.Thanks : )